# Jenkins pipeline: execute end to end suites based on changed file(s)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline, e2e-testing

I have a project which is well decoupled in several components. We use Jenkins to start our pipeline and, every time we push a change to a file, a set of e2e suites is executed.

Now, given that a change in module A (even if they are still in the same repo, for now) does not break anything in modules B and C, I'd like to know if there is a way in Jenkins, to dynamically build our pipeline based on the files changed in git, so that if we change a file in module A,  only suite A is executed.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: Since you have decoupled your system into several components, I think it's better to build different pipelines for different modules